# Problem from Royden Real Analysis (Lebesgue Outer Measure Problem)

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Below is the problem and my attempted solution, however, I have a question about it.

**Problem:** Show that a set $E$ is measurable if and only if for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a closed set $F$ and open set $\mathcal{O}$ for which $F \subseteq E \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ and
$m^*(\mathcal{O} \setminus F) < \epsilon$.

(my attempted) **Solution:** $E$ is measurable if and only if the following two hold:

$$(i) \text{ For each } \epsilon > 0, \text{ there exists an open set } \mathcal{O} \text{ containing } E \text{ for which } m^*(\mathcal{O} \setminus E) < \epsilon$$

$$(ii) \text{ For each } \epsilon > 0, \text{ there exists a closed set } F \text{ contained in } E \text{ for which } m^*(E \setminus F) < \epsilon.$$

In particular, we have that

$$(i) \text{ For } \frac{\epsilon}{2} > 0, \text{ there exists an open set } \mathcal{O} \text{ containing } E \text{ for which } m^*(\mathcal{O} \setminus E) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

$$(ii) \text{ For } \frac{\epsilon}{2} > 0, \text{ there exists a closed set } F \text{ contained in } E \text{ for which } m^*(E \setminus F) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Since both $E$ and $F$ are measurable sets, we have by the excision property

$$(i) \text{ For } \frac{\epsilon}{2} > 0, \text{ there exists an open set } \mathcal{O} \text{ containing } E \text{ for which } m^*(\mathcal{O}) - m^*(E) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

$$(ii) \text{ For } \frac{\epsilon}{2} > 0, \text{ there exists a closed set } F \text{ contained in } E \text{ for which } m^*(E) - m^*(F) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Adding both equations gives

$$(iii) \text{ For } \frac{\epsilon}{2} > 0, \text{ there exists a closed set } F \text{ and} \text{ open set } \mathcal{O} \text{, such that, } F \subseteq E \subseteq \mathcal{O} \text{ for which} $$
$$m^*(\mathcal{O}) - m^*(E) + m^*(E) - m^*(F) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
$$m^*(\mathcal{O}) - m^*(F) < \epsilon.$$
Since $F$ is measurable, we have by the excision property

$$m^*(\mathcal{O} \setminus F) < \epsilon,$$
as desired.

The question I have is, can I say "for $\frac{\epsilon}{2} > 0$".

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to say for the sufficient condition: let $\varepsilon>0$, by regularity of outer measures, $\exists F$ closed and $O$ open s.t. $m^*(E\setminus O)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $F\subset E$ s.t. $m^*(E\setminus F)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then you apply countable additivity.

For the necessity condition, just use monotonicity of outer measures.

This argument should avoid your question.